# How to set cursor position in softkeyboard(not in EditText or TextView!!!) in Android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, cursor-position, soft-keyboard

The following code works for only 1000 characters. If there are more than 1000 characters, the cursor will jump back to the end of 999 characters and start working again.

This is because `getTextBeforeCursor(n,flag)` can offer only the `n` number of characters before the current cursor position. In EditText, however, we can get all the text by using `getText()` method and we can get the length as well. But how to get length of the entire text in the composing text area so that I can set the cursor position to anywhere I want.

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

String str = ic.getTextBeforeCursor(1000,0).toString();
ic.setSelection(str.length()-1,str.length()-1);
```

Comment: No,it is a custom softkeyboard which can be used in any text fields/area.

Comment: I found it!Just share other ppl
sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);

Comment: @Naung: Please post this comment as an answer and accept it so that this question gets marked as answered and the people coming to this thread to search for an answer, they find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

> It's very simple. I just got solution when I am working on soft
>   keyboard.

```
CharSequence textBeforeCursor = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextBeforeCursor(1000, 0);

CharSequence textAfterCursor = getCurrentInputConnection().getTextAfterCursor(1000, 0);
```

> then by just calculating and adding of lengths of above two values you
>   can get length of composing text area.
>
> If any problems just inform me.